# iOS Safari pin link to homescreen: 3D touch options

Tags: html, ios, safari, 3dtouch

As specified in the Apple developer library, Safari allows developers to specify icons for home screen quick links to websites:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

Now with 3D touch, the obvious use of this feature would be to specify 3D touch links to search, and other popular pages on your website.

I have been reading through the developer API, I cannot find if this is permitted, which leads me to believe it isn't, there also appears to be no discussion on SO regarding this.

Does anybody have a method they know of on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There’s no existing API for this; if you’d like support for it, you should [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com).